# Traversing a tree and assigning a subtree in Julia

Tags: macros, julia

I am trying to manipulate a tree in Julia. The tree is created as an object. All I want is substituting the one of the branches with another one. I can do it manually but can not do it by using a recursion function.

```
mutable struct ILeaf
    majority::Any # +1 when prediction is correct
    values::Vector # num_of_samples
    indicies::Any # holds the index of training samples
end

mutable struct INode
    featid::Integer
    featval::Any
    left::Union{ILeaf,INode}
    right::Union{ILeaf,INode}
end

ILeafOrNode = Union{ILeaf,INode}
```

And my function for chaning the tree is (tree is original one where, by using LR_STACK, I am willing to change one of the branches and substitute it with the subtree. ) :

```
function traverse_and_assign(tree, subtree, lr_stack) # by using Global LR_stack
    if top(lr_stack) == 0
        tree = subtree 
    elseif top(lr_stack) == :LEFT
        pop!(lr_stack)
        return traverse_and_assign(tree.left, subtree, lr_stack)
    else # right otherwise
        pop!(lr_stack)
        return traverse_and_assign(tree.right, lr_stack)
    end
end
```

What happens is that I cannot change the original tree.

On the other hand :

```
tree.left.left = subtree
```

works perfectly fine.

What is wrong with my code ? Do I have to write a macro for this ?
B.R.

**edit#1**
In order to generate data :

```
n, m = 10^3, 5 ;
features = randn(n, m);
lables = rand(1:2, n);
```

**edit#2**
use 100 samples for training the decision tree :

```
base_learner = build_iterative_tree(labels, features, [1:20;])
```

then give  other samples one by one :

```
i = 21
feature = features[21, :], label = labels[21]
gtree_stack, lr_stack = enter_iterate_on_tree(base_learner, feature[:], i, label[1])
```

get the indices of incorrect samples

```
ids = subtree_ids(gtree_stack)
```

build the subtree:

```
subtree = build_iterative_tree(l, f, ids)
```

update the original tree(base_learner):

```
traverse_and_assign(base_learner, subtree, lr_stack)
```

Comment: Could you write [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (known also as [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example))

Comment: Actually, I am modifying the [DecisionTree.jl](https://github.com/bensadeghi/DecisionTree.jl) package. Nearly, all functions that I am using are from there. I just changed immutable types to mutable. Besides that, I am holding a stack in order to determine which subtree should be replaced by a new one.

Comment: It is difficult work to trying understand. For example your aim is to use recursion but function `my_traverse_and_assign` is calling functions with different name `traverse_and_assign` is it wanted? Who could know without MWE?? BTW there is convention to add ! to function name if it change its parameters. So `my_traverse_and_assign!` is probably better name.

Comment: This is the link to "my" package : [IterativeTree.jl](https://github.com/kadir-gunel/IterativeTree.jl)

Comment: I fixed the naming of the traverse_and_assign function.

Answer (score 0):

I still miss MWE but maybe I could help with one problem without it.

In Julia value is bind to variable. Parameters in functions are new variables. Let's do test what does it mean:

```
function test_assign!(tree, subtree) 
    tree = subtree
    return tree
end

a = 4;
b = 5;

test_assign!(a, b)  # return 5

show(a)  #  4 ! a is not changed!
```

What happend? value 4 was bind to `tree` and value 5 was bind to `subtree`. 
`subtree`'s value (5) was bind to `tree`.

And nothing else! Means `a` is stil bound to 4.

How to could we change `a`? This will work:

```
mutable struct SimplifiedNode
       featid::Integer
end

function test_assign!(tree, subtree) 
    tree.featid = subtree.featid
end

a = SimplifiedNode(4)
b = SimplifiedNode(5)

test_assign!(a, b)
show(a)  # SimplifiedNode(5)
```

Why? What happend?

Value of `a` (which is something like pointer to mutable struct) is bind to `tree` and value of `b` is bound to `subtree`.

So `a` and `tree` are bound to same structure! Means that if we change that structure `a` is bind to changed structure.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  I finally created a [working sample] (https://github.com/kadir-gunel/for_today).